# String pointer as argument in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

So, I'm trying to do the following with some C code:

```
int eval_setence(char *words){
...
}

void main(){
char *words[8];
eval_setence(words);
}
```

But I'm don't know why the code is not compiling, I assume the function is getting a double pointer to `words[8]`. Could someone explain what's going on?

I'm trying to do operations with the `words[8]` inside the function, i.e:

```
if(words[i] == 'Wow')
...
```

Comment: Woops, forgot to add, this in in C

Comment: Please post the compiler output.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev /root/Desktop/server.c|112|note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’|

Comment: Use `char **` as your function argument. Also note that you can't compare strings with `==`, and strings must be double-quoted, not single-quoted.

Comment: @Zetsuno so just do what compiler says.

Comment: @ace That did manage to compile, but, per example, if I want to print them all it seems I can't use the strlen() function, any ideas why?

Comment: You should be able to use `strlen(words[0])`, `strlen(words[1])` etc.

Comment: @Zetsuno just read more about pointers in C language. Nothing to do in C without strong knowledge about pointers.

Comment: I suggest abandoning whatever tutorial, textbook, or instructor you're currently using and finding one with enough knowledge of the language not to suggest `void main()`. `int main(void)` is correct.

Comment: `'Wow'` is legal, but it's not what you want. Character literals use single quotes, and normally represent single characters: `'W'`. String literals use double quotes: `"Wow"`. But you can't directly compare strings for equality.

Comment: @KeithThompson In my college professors use either void main() or int main(), but what's so bad about using void?

Comment: @Zetsuno: It's non-standard. The C standard specifies either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, or equivalent. Other implementation-defined forms are permitted, but there is really no good reason to use `void main()`. The very same standard that introduced the `void` keyword also specified `int` as the return type for `main`. See questions 11.12a and following in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 3):

```
int eval_setence(char *words){
...
}

void main(){
char words[8];
eval_setence(words);
}
```

Your words variable was a pointer to a char pointer, you should define an array this way:

```
type var[len];
```

Not:

```
type *var[len];
```

Or, if you need a two dimensional array (which I suppose you do), you should define it like this:

```
type var[len1][len2];
```

This should be trivial however.

Comment: You're right, it was trivial, I was just overthinking it way too much, thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
char *words[8];
```

declares `words` as an array of pointers to chars.  When this is passed to a function it is converted to a pointer to a pointer to chars.  If you want an array of "strings", then this is correct, and you will need to change your function prototype to be expecting `**char`.

On a tangential note, `if(words[i] == 'Wow')` is not good [c](/questions/tagged/c) for a number of reasons.  First the `'` character is used to denote a **single** character.  Strings are enclosed with `"`.  Second, string comparison cannot be accomplished with that sort of comparison.  You need to use the [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html) like

```
if (strcmp(words[i], "Wow") == 0)
```